# React Native: Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I have always built React Native projects with either the `react-native-cli` or Expo.

I just cloned this React Native project that has gradle in it and I am running `npm run build` in accordance with the `scripts` as I see it in `package.json` file:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "nps",
    "test": "nps setup",
    "build": "nps build",
    "setup": "nps setup && nps appcenter",
    "postinstall": "rm -f ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/__fixtures__/files/package.json"
  },
```

When I run `npm run build`, my roadblock seems to be related to gradle which I have zero experience with.

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
```

I accepted the license agreements for the SDK already and I have no idea what this error is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to upgrade node to 8.10.x.It will downgrad your npm to 5.6.0 Then update npm using  `npm install npm -g` and it will update Your npm to 5.7.1